# Graphql throwing "The repeat()-traversal was not defined" on query

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js, amazon-neptune

I am using neptune and graphql and I am getting this error:

```
"Server error: {\"detailedMessage\":\"The repeat()-traversal was not defined: RepeatStep(until([NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep, NeptuneHasStep([~label.eq("sample"), ~key.eq(id)])]),emit(true))\",\"code\":\"InternalFailureException\",\"requestId\":\"<id>\"}
```

here is my query:

```
 g
.V(keyId)
.repeat(__.outE('RELATIONSHIP').inV())
.dedup()
.until(__.and(__.hasLabel('sample'),
__.hasKey('id')))
.emit()
.filter(__.label().is('sample'))
.dedup()
.values('id')
.toList();
```

How do I correctly repeat this query?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that the closing paren for the repeat is in the wrong place. It needs to be after `dedup` and before `until`. As you are not using properties from the edge, `outE().inV` could be replaced with just `out()` if you prefer. I'm a bit curious about the loops termination condition as it seems you just want to find a vertex with a "sample" label and a property called "id" but you don't care about the value of that property. I'm also not sure about the `filter` you have in the query. That really duplicates what was done in the `until` and if really needed can just be written as `hasLabel('sample')`.

```java
 g.V(keyId).
   repeat(__.outE('RELATIONSHIP').inV().dedup()).
   until(__.and(__.hasLabel('sample'), __.hasKey('id'))).emit().
  filter(__.label().is('sample')).
  dedup().
  values('id').
  toList();
```

If any of what I wrote above does not make sense or there are aspects to the problem I have missed, please add a comment and I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I should have picked two different names, I am going to edit and update to be something like "parent" and "child". It turns out that the issue was neptune updated and doesn't support the way I had implemented something else. this looks much cleaner though, so i am going to try and use this too